# A blank Option automatically append in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending text box value in select box option when we click on submit button, its working proper but when this value appends in select box it shows a one more blank option, I have checked in inspect element, why its happening, what should we do for this. I have not found this reason so far.

I am appending text box value in select box option when we click on submit button, its working proper but when this value appends in select box it shows a one more blank option, I have checked in inspect element, why its happening, what should we do for this. I have not found this reason so far.

```js
$(function(){
    var x=[];
    
    $("#itemDone").click(function(){
        var y=$("#itemType").val();
        var z=$("#itemName").val();
        x.push(z);
    
        for(i=1; i<x.length; i++){
            $("#itemType").append('<option value="x[i]">'+x[i]+'<option>');
            $("#itemplace1 ul").append('<li>'+x[i]+'</li>');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="row">
    
    
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background: #efefef;; height: 100vh;">
    <br />
    <div id="itemplace1">
    <ul></ul>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-9" style="background: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.25); height: 100vh;">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="itemName" />
    <select id="itemType">
    
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <button id="itemDone">Submit</button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are reappending the whole x array, and not just the new value? Also array's start at index 0 not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix to you code:

```js
$(function(){
    var x=[];
    
    $("#itemDone").click(function(){
        var y=$("#itemType").val();
        var z=$("#itemName").val();
        x.push(z);
        
        $("#itemType").children().remove();
        $("#itemplace1 ul").children().remove();
        
        for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            $("#itemType").append('<option value="x[i]">'+x[i]+'</option>');
            $("#itemplace1 ul").append('<li>'+x[i]+'</li>');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background: #efefef;; height: 100vh;">
      <br />
      <div id="itemplace1">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9" style="background: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.25); height: 100vh;">
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="itemName" />
        <select id="itemType">

        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button id="itemDone">Submit</button>
      </div>    
</div>
```

1. Clean some of the html code (`<br />` element should self-close).
2. Clean the `#itemType` and `#itemplace1 ul` elements on each click.
3. The `<option>` element should be closed with `</option>` and not another `<option>` tag.
4. The `for` loop should start at 0 and not 1

Answer (score 0):

I think the wrong option tag in closing, that is not a closed option but a new opening one, is causing the browser to bad render the select.

Please try using a corret html markup and see if it solves.